# ROR + ActiveAdmin + Carrierwave, editing after uploading multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, activeadmin

I have a ROR application running ActiveAdmin and using CarrierWave to upload images. I got a model: Product, which allows for multiple ProductImages. All seems to go quite fine when just adding a new product and choosing several images to upload. But once I want to edit that product the image doesn't seem to actually be uploaded, plus I get the following error:

```
undefined method `image_changed?'
```

My assumption is that the initial uploading doesn't do much and therefor ends up empty on edit.

Here is a snippet of the Admin form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form(:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :name
        f.input :descr, :label => "Description"
        f.input :brand, :as => :select, :collection => Brand.all, :member_label => :name, :label => "Brand"

      # tags
      f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, '/products/autocomplete_tag_name', :"data-delimiter" => ', '
      f.input :tag_list, :hint => "Comma delimited tags"
    end

    f.has_many :product_images do |pi|
      pi.inputs "Product Images" do
        if !pi.object.nil?
          pi.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => 'Destroy?'
        end
        pi.input :image_name
        pi.input :image
      end
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

*edit*

I know one thing more, the images do get uploaded on creation of the post, its the edit from that acts up..

Comment: I have currently same problem - did You find any solution? :/

Comment: Same problem... cant delete after added.. any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (but with Paperclip) a while ago. The solution (not obvious) was that the image was not updated IF the user did not provide its password in the edit form to confirm the update.

So, if you didn't try this, it might be worth: ask the user to enter its password when editing the Product and see if images are then correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently.
Please update your form field like below. You have to set the input field as file.

```
pi.input :image, :as => :file
```